# Extract part of 2D-List/Matrix/List of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to extract a part of a two-dimensional list (=list of lists) in Python. I use Mathematica a lot, and there it is very convenient to write

```
matrix[[2;;4,10;;13]]
```

which would extract the part of the matrix which is between the 2nd and 4th row as well as the 10th and 13th column.

In Python, I just used

```
[x[firstcolumn:lastcolumn+1] for x in matrix[firstrow:lastrow+1]]
```

Is there also a more elegant or efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want is [numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and the slice operator `:`.

```
>>> import numpy

>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[5,5,5]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [5, 5, 5]])

>>> a[0:2,0:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: @user1447622 - you're welcome! If the answer works, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark (unless you're waiting to see if you get other answers, which is perfectly fine - I just thought I'd point it out in case you didn't know how it works, since you're a new user)